# Show and run PWAs in custom launcher

Tags: android, progressive-web-apps, android-launcher

I am writing custom launcher and almost at the end of my work. I would like to have the functionality to add PWA to my launcher home screen.

I've created new activity that will handle new **PWA**s, added it to `AndroidManifest` with `CONFIRM_PIN_SHORTCUT` intent filter and managed to receive `PinItemRequest` in my activity when pwa got installed from browser.

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```xml
        <activity android:name=".HandleShortcutActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.content.pm.action.CONFIRM_PIN_SHORTCUT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

**HandleShortcutActivity.kt**:

```kotlin
class HandleShortcutActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            handlePins()
        }
        //LauncherApps.getPinItemRequest( this.intent );
    }


    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    private fun handlePins() {
        val launcherApps = applicationContext.getSystemService(Context.LAUNCHER_APPS_SERVICE) as LauncherApps
        val request = launcherApps.getPinItemRequest(intent)

        Timber.d("handlePins: request = \n{shortcutInfo:\n\tlongLabel=${request.shortcutInfo?.longLabel}\n\tpackage=${request.shortcutInfo?.`package`}")

        this.finish()
    }

}
```

What information from `shortcutInfo` I can use to correctly run **PWA** from launcher? The package of **PWA** is **com.android.chrome** and it is accessible, but I can't see any additional info that could help me to run **PWA**.

Also, how can I get the icon from this received `PinItemRequset` which will I use as an icon in my launcher?